# How to get only the last two files within a folder using c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to get only the last two files within a folder, so that I can merge them together using c#. The files are csv files and I've looked at File.CreationTime, but don't know exactly how to compare on it, so that I'm working only with the last two files.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use Linq:

```
List<FileInfo> lastTwoFiles = directoryInfo.GetFiles()
                              .OrderBy(x => x.CreationTime).Take(2).ToList()
```

Or use OrderByDescending if you want the two newest files.

Comment: I'm not real familiar with LINQ. How could I do this without using LINQ?

Comment: You have to: 1- pick the first two files. 2- go through all the other files and compare for every loop: If the file has a CreationTime lower than the one you have, replace it to this one and so on. I could write the code for this but it is basic programming you should try it yourself.